# How to show that the variance estimator of a gaussian is biased?

Tags: normal-distribution, unbiased-estimator

The sample variance of $m$ samples from a gaussian is  $$ \hat{\sigma}^2_m=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m(x^{(i)}-\hat{\mu}_m)^2$$

How do i show that the sample variance $\hat{\sigma}_m^2$ is biased ?
I.e  $$E[\hat{\sigma}_m^2] = E[\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m(x^{(i)} - \hat{\mu}_m)^2] = \frac{m-1}{m}\sigma^2$$

Comment: [This paper](https://maxwell.ict.griffith.edu.au/sso/biased_variance.pdf) might help you.

Comment: @bilibraker hey thanks for the paper link !

Comment: The simplest test is to drop the estimator from a great height.